# Why do most characters have perfect, white teeth even if the film's setting makes them unlikely?

Tags: production, realism

I understand the premium that's placed on perfectly straight pearly white teeth in American society (or at least I think I do) but one thing that really irks me is the dental perfection on display in post-apocalyptic/dystopian films and television series and other instances where it's not realistic.

I'm thinking of such films as the [Terminator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_%28franchise%29) series and series like *[The Walking Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_%28TV_series%29)*, where let's face it, there are much more pressing things to worry about than veneers and braces. We're now into season 5 of *The Walking Dead* and still the teeth are perfect there! You could reasonably expect a little bit of decay and yellowing to have taken place.

Let's even forget about the future and look to Downton Abbey - not a crooked canine to be seen there either, even among the downstairs crew.

Why don't the show runners choose to abandon this fiction and inject a dose of realism into things?

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/26218/49.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, those tags make much more sense. From the linked question you posted as well, a nice link to TV Tropes: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EternallyPearlyWhiteTeeth

Comment: I'd even be inclined to close the other one as a duplicate of this one, since your question seems to be much more general and the answer is probably the same anyway (i.e. *"because noone in the production cares enough and those guys are supposed to look at least remotely beautiful"*).

Comment: You have the standing to start that process, in this community I'm a lightweight ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't close-vote the other one as a duplicate, since stupidly enough that's only possible if the parent question already has upvoted answers, but at least I flagged it for moderator attention.

Comment: Seeing as you basically led me to the TV Tropes page I have no issue with you proposing that as an answer which I accept and upvote?

Comment: Huh? I didn't link to any TVTropes page, I'd rarely ever link to there, let alone put it into an answer. I don't really have a well thought out answer and don't know what that TVTropes link says, so I'll refrain for now from answering until I might have time to structure my rather gut-feeling based comment into a proper answer. Maybe someone has a better or at least better-phrased answer anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18446/discussion-between-noonand-and-napoleon-wilson).

Comment: I'm not sure why you decided to bash America in your first sentence. America's supposed need for straight white teeth has not-so-much to do with the _English_ actors working on Downtown Abbey. So, it's less America's premium on... than it is the film industry as a whole. After all, looking at images of many well known Bollywood actors shows me they have that same premium, and your average Indian actor isn't doing it to land a role on an American production, they are quite the mega-stars in _India_

Comment: If I've offended you then please accept my apologies. The intent wasn't to poke the nationalistic bear here, it's based on personal experience and some observations. If we accept that the vast majority of cinematic and/or televisual output originates in the US and is primarily aimed at US audiences then it makes sense to aim at what your core audience is. Here Downton is an example, I could just as easily have said Deadwood but the former is current.

Comment: No offense taken, honestly. My extended point was that, for example, look at so called Bollywood productions. There are many movies made each year, intended primarily for a local, national (Indian) audience. Most in America will never see them. Most of the actors that appear in them will never have an audience in 'greater' America, beyond those countrymen who have moved here. Yet, looking at images of the big stars, they have done the same beautification that American actors have. It's not America's fault. It's an industry effect.

Comment: It's harder to put makeup on teeth that sticks when you want it, and comes off when you don't, and telling the actors/actresses to actually HAVE poor dental hygiene is probably a non-starter

Comment: While some uglying up can be expected, do you really think they'd not cast or disfigure top actors/actresses because of the dental work?  On a side note, my son read for a lead part in a small independent film, and the director liked his reading the best, but couldn't get past the fact that this poor, impoverished, violent street kid would have had thousands of dollars in orthodontic hardware had he cast my son.  Not the straight teeth as much as the undeniable hardware.  BTW - I've never had work done on my teeth, and they are perfectly straight.  Comes from having a big mouth, I guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it ***is*** fiction; entertainment, first and foremost. It's not *intended* to be a scientifically accurate treatise on *exactly* how it would be like in a post apocalyptic world short on people. Folks would be milling around all day gathering roots, scratching themselves, and wondering where to walk to next. Not exactly great entertainment.

How the various characters look and act is all about the elements of story-telling. People who are supposed to be likable in a story are generally made to be, um… likeable. That means the visuals are generally pleasant to look at so you can have that fully-immersive experience of being right there with them and completely empathizing with them  as the main protagonists. You don't want your main characters to elicit a reaction like "gross, why do I care what happens to them at all?"

So they DO get squalid and unhygenic if the scene calls for it… but only enough to tell the story without becoming unpleasantly repulsive — unless that's what the storyline happens to call for at the time — but we generally leave that for the bad guys.

Comment: +1. Same reasoning explains why almost all of the actors on these shows are much more good-looking than average (and the only ones who aren't have specifically non-sexual roles, like "grandmother" or "wise old man"): because audience members generally prefer to watch attractive characters (whether the audience members are aware of it or not) and tooth decay is not attractive.

Comment: We all know it's fiction, you don't need to condescendingly point that out. *"Folks would be milling around all day gathering roots, scratching themselves, and wondering where to walk to next."* That has **nothing** to do with the question asked. This is a question of appearances, not story progression. If they didn't care about being accurate, the actors would all be walking around in brand new designer clothes.

Comment: Please feel free to provide a better answer.