# Do movie stars need regular teeth whitening?

Tags: make-up

I don't think everyone's teeth is naturally white. I know mine aren't, no matter how many times I brush, my teeth don't appear white in the mirror. They do appear shiny, like pearls, but never white. Although I could discount the time when someone's shining white light on them; then they do appear white.

But in movies, everyone strictly must have white teeth, sometimes I see some people's teeth appear *too* white.

Do stars whose teeth aren't naturally white need regular whitening by a dentist?

Comment: [Related](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26218/why-do-the-pirates-have-white-teeth)

Comment: No.  Plenty don't have pearly white teeth ([Steve Buschemi](http://www.afternoonspecial.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/2teeth-0911-10.jpg) comes to mind).  However, it's likely that leading men and women do this, just as they do other aesthetic upkeep such as hair replacement and skin tightening.

Comment: In any case, I don't know who's going to *force* them to do it, so I'm not sure what 'need' really means. They don't need to do anything to their bodies that they don't want to.

Comment: IMO the only reason most celibrities are known is that they all meet certain standards and having white teeth is just the minimum.

Comment: @Walt Well, I'd say Steve is an exception. I even saw him ranked in the most ugly actors poll on some website once. Probably of no importance, but still. I'd say ones whose appearance matters very much, like top models or actors like Tom Cruise or Pierce Brosnan...

Comment: @Alexandre I don't think banner ads qualify then. I've seen quite a few super-white(with a human touch, if you get what I mean) teeth on those.

Comment: Rembrandt toothpaste - 12 quid a tube... go for it, it's cheaper than the dentist. It's not compulsory, but it's in every prospective actor's potential armoury. ;)) [not an advert, just an observation of what actor-hopefuls can & do use]

Comment: post editing process can make teeth whiter

Answer (score 2):

### Do they *need* regular teeth whitening? Sure, if that's their image

According to [one article](https://www.raconteur.net/healthcare/lure-of-the-all-american-white-smile):

> A staggering 45 million Americans – 14 per cent of the population – have had professional teeth whitening, according to data guru Mintel. This is compared to just 3 per cent in the UK.

It appears that Americans value a white smile very highly:

> ...half of Americans believe a bright white smile is the most memorable feature when first meeting someone, according to the American Association of Cosmetic Dentists (AACD), more important even than what that person says.

If you are an actor looking to 'break' America, you may consider having a "desirable" smile to enhance your image.

While many roles might require false teeth which enhance teeth in some way (for example Jim Carrey in *The Mask* or Rami Malek in *Bohemian Rhapsody*), an actor may well want to maintain a certain image off-camera if they felt it might lead to better public image, or perhaps more regular roles.

In a similar way, some actors (male and female) will wear makeup to red-carpet appearances - so it's clear that there is an expectation either from themselves, or from others (perhaps management) to maintain a "perfect image".